# What the difference between TNetEncoding.URL.EncodeForm and TNetEncoding.URL.EncodeQuery?

Tags: delphi

I don't quite understand why their is 2 functions ? the doc is empty but it's seam that one is to encode the `http get query string` and the other is to encode the `http post data string`. But as far as i Understand both must be encoded in the same way (ie: `urlencoded`) so why 2 different functions ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the code for them in unit `System.NetEncoding.pas`?

Comment: yes, they are not the same :(

Comment: I think that @StijnSanders was imagining that you would read the code and attempt to understand it. After all, with methods that aren't documented, what else can you do? Or would you prefer we did that for you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : It's not about the code and how it's implemented it's why we have 2 differents functions that produce 2 differents results :( for me it's a mistake. before we had httpEncode but now emb remove it

Comment: And the code doesn't tell you anything about how the functions are meant to be used. I think if you dig into the RFCs you'll find that different parts of a URL are encoded differently

Comment: const QueryUnsafeChars: TUnsafeChars = [Ord('"'), Ord(''''), Ord('<'), Ord('>'), Ord('#')] and const FormUnsafeChars: TUnsafeChars = [Ord('"'), Ord(''''), Ord(':'), Ord(';'), Ord('<'), Ord('='), Ord('>'),
      Ord('@'), Ord('['), Ord(']'), Ord('^'), Ord('`'), Ord('{'), Ord('}'), Ord('|'), Ord('/'), Ord('\'), Ord('?'), Ord('#'),
      Ord('&'), Ord('!'), Ord('$'), Ord('('), Ord(')'), Ord(','), Ord('~')];

Comment: and as you see the ? and & are not even in the queryUnsafeChars, where it's absolutely must be !

Comment: Never mind. I can't help like this.

Comment: no problem @DavidHeffernan anyway i think it's a mistake of emb .... i found the httpencode in xe4 and copy past this code to use in tokyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the functions escapes more unsafe characters than the other, in case any of them may be used as a delimiter in one of the transport layers the request gets transferred over.